# Heroku Row Count Does Not Match DB

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, row

I have built and deployed a Django application on Heroku and I am trying to estimate how many users I can handle before I need to upgrade from Heroku Dev. Thus I have created a user and deleted it but the row count on the  remains the same, 283

To try and see what's happening I counted the row manually using postgresql studio. I get a total of 352 rows or 69 rows over what Heroku says I have. Here is the breakdown of my rows.

- Total    352
- Custom Model1    9
- Custom Model2    24
- Custom Model3    9
- email address    13
- email confirmation   18
- auth permission  48
- auth user    13
- admin log    11
- content type 16
- session  168
- site 1
- migration history    22

Does anybody know how Heroku calculates your row count?

Thanks!

Comment: I imagine it's calculated "lazily" - periodically by a batch job of some kind, and probably using sampling and estimation to avoid having to scan the whole tables. It could even be using PostgreSQL's own statistics, as generated by autovacuum analyze.

Comment: I've waited a day and still get the same number of rows but perhaps your right.